# how to reduce product quantity using ajax in asp.net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i am trying to do inventory with pos system. When the pos system working perfectly but not reduce product quantity using ajax.
how to reduce product quantity when order successfully submitted to database and then we submitted quantity will be reduce from product table in asp.net core

This is salesorder.cshtm

```
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom:50px;">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="WholesalePrice" name="WholesalePrice" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Details
        </legend>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="OrderNumber">Number</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="OrderNumber" class="form-control" id="OrderNumber" readonly />
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrderNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="CustomerId">Customer</label>
                    <select id="Customer" name="Customer" asp-for="CustomerId" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomerId" class="form-control select20">
                        <option selected disabled></option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="PaymentType" class="control-label">Payment Type</label>
                    <select id="PaymentType" asp-for="PaymentType" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SoftdrinkManagment.Enum.PaymentType>()">
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="PaymentType" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <textarea id="Description" class="form-control" asp-for="Description" rows="3" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />

    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Add Product
        </legend>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">Product</label>
                    <select id="Product" name="Product" class="form-control select20">
                        <option selected disabled></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">Unit Price</label>
                    @Html.Editor("Price", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Price", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">AvailableQuantity</label>
                    @Html.Editor("AvailableQuantity", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "AvailableQuantity", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
                    @Html.Editor("Quantity", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Quantity" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">Discount</label>
                    @Html.Editor("Discount", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Discount" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">Tax</label>
                    @Html.Editor("Tax", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Tax" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label">Total Amount</label>
                    @Html.Editor("Amount", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Amount", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="margin-top:30px">
                        <span><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Add To List</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />

    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Product Lists
        </legend>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm table-hover table-bordered cust-datatable" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th hidden>ProductId</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>UnitPrice</th>
                        <th>Quantity </th>
                        <th>Discount</th>
                        <th>Tax</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="Items">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <fieldset>
        <div class="container" style="right:90%">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8">
                    <label asp-for="FinalTotal">Total Amount</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="FinalTotal" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Amount" id="TotalAmount" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinalTotal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8">
                    <label asp-for="PaidAmount">Given Amount</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="PaidAmount" id="GivenAmount" class="form-control" placeholder="Given Amount" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaidAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8">
                    <label asp-for="BalanceAmount">Change Amount</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="BalanceAmount" class="form-control" id="ChangeAmount" placeholder="Change Amount" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BalanceAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-8">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Order" class="button success btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btnSubmit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

this is salesorder.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //submit btn event

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var customer = $("#Customer").val();
        if (customer == null) {
            $.notify('Customer Feild Required', { globalPosition: 'top-center', color: "#fff", background: "#D44950" });
        }
        else {
            var list = [];
            $('#Items tr').each(function (index, ele) {
                var orderedItem = {
                    ProductId: $('.productId', this).text(),
                    Product: $('.productName', this).text(),
                    UnitPrice: parseFloat($('.price', this).text()),
                    Quantity: parseInt($('.quantity', this).text()),
                    Discount: parseInt($('.discount', this).text()),
                    Tax: parseInt($('.tax', this).text()),
                    Total: parseFloat($('.amount', this).text())
                };
                list.push(orderedItem);
            });
            console.log(list);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Sales/SalesOrder',
                datatype: "Json",
                data: {
                    CustomerId: $("#Customer").val(),
                    OrderNumber: $("#OrderNumber").val(),
                    PaymentType: $("#PaymentType").val(),
                    FinalTotal: parseFloat($("#TotalAmount").val()),
                    PaidAmount: parseFloat($("#GivenAmount").val()),
                    BalanceAmount: parseFloat($("#ChangeAmount").val()),
                    Description: $("#Description").val(),
                    OrderDetails: list
                },
                success: function () {
                    
                },
                error: function (error) {

                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    //add button event
    $("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
        var productId = $('#Product').val();
        var productName = $("#Product option:selected").text();
        var price = $("#Price").val();
        var quantity = $("#Quantity").val();
        var discount = $("#Discount").val();
        var tax = $("#Tax").val();
        var amount = $("#Amount").val();
        var avlqty = $("#AvailableQuantity").val();


        if (avlqty < quantity ) {
            $.notify('Product Not Enough! Check Available Quantity', { globalPosition: 'top-center', color: "#fff", background: "#D44950" });
        } else
        if (productId == null) {
            $.notify('Product Feild Required!', { globalPosition: 'top-center', color: "#fff", background: "#D44950" });
        } else
        if (quantity == 0 || quantity == null) {
            $.notify('Quantity Feild Required', { globalPosition: 'top-center', color: "#fff", background: "#D44950" });
        }
        else {
            var row = `<tr>
                <td class="productId" hidden>${productId}</td>
                <td class="productName">${productName}</td>
                <td class="price">${price}</td>
                <td class="quantity">${quantity}</td>
                <td class="discount">${discount}</td>
                <td class="tax">${tax}</td>
                <td class="amount">${amount}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btnDelete">
                        <span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>`;

            $('#Items').append(row);
            calculateSum();
            ResetItem();
            //clearValue();
        }

    });


    //get products
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Sales/GetProducts",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#Product').append('<option value="' + value.productId + '">' + value.productName + '</option>');
            });
            LoadProductsData($("#Product option:selected").val());
        }
    });
    $("#Product").change(function () {
        LoadProductsData($("#Product option:selected").val());
    });

//get products details
function LoadProductsData(id) {
    $('#Price').val('0.00');
    $('#AvailableQuantity').val("0");
    $('#Amount').val("0.00");
    $('#Tax').val("0.00");
    $('#Quantity').val("0");
    $('#Discount').val("0.00");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Sales/GetProductById",
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { productId: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $("#Price").val(parseFloat(value.sellingPrice).toFixed(2));
                $("#AvailableQuantity").val(value.quantity);
                $("#WholesalePrice").val(parseFloat(value.wholeSalePrice).toFixed(2));
            });

        }
    });
}
```

And this is salescontroller.cs

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext db;
    private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;
    private readonly ICategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private readonly IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    public SalesController(AppDbContext db, IProductRepository productRepository,
        ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository, IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Order> order;
        order = db.Orders.ToList();
        return View(order);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SalesOrder()
    {
        ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(db.OfflineCustomer, "CustomerId", "FirstName");
        return View(new Order());

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SalesOrder(Order data)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(data);
        data.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

        orderRepository.Add(data);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
    


    public IActionResult CustomerList()
    {
        return View(customerRepository.GetAll());
    }
    public IActionResult CategoryList()
    {
        return View(categoryRepository.GetAll());
    }
    public IActionResult ProductList()
    {
        return View(productRepository.GetAll());
    }

    public JsonResult Customers()
    {
        return Json(customerRepository.GetAll());
    }
    public JsonResult GetCategories()
    {
        return Json(categoryRepository.GetAll());
    }
    public JsonResult GetProducts()
    {
        return Json(productRepository.GetAll().Where(s => s.Quantity > 0).Where(e=>e.ExpiryDate>DateTime.Now));
    }
    public JsonResult GetProductById(Guid productId)
    {
        return Json(productRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.ProductId == productId));
    }
}
```

}

This is ProductModal.cs

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The ProductName field is required.")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Number field is required.")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryModel")]
    public Guid? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public ProductCategoryModel ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The ManufactureDate field is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date..")]
    public DateTime? ManufactureDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The ExpiryDate field is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date..")]
    public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    public decimal ManufacturePrice { get; set; }

    public decimal WholeSalePrice { get; set; } 

    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; } 

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string StockInBy { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

This Order.cs

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("OfflineCustomer")]
    [Required]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public OfflineCustomer Customer { get; set; }
    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal PaidAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal BalanceAmount { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This is OrderDetail

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    
    [Key]
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductModel")]
    [Required]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public ProductModel ProductModel { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: When you click the "Save Order" button does it hit your javascript code?

Comment: yes it's working but product quantity is not reducing!!

Comment: Well, you don't do anything on the view after the action `success: function () { },`

Comment: Why you think the quantity will reduce? I can't see the related code, you should mark it clearly and delete unrelated code when you post your question.

Comment: nope, this is inventory + pos system. when we sell the product from pos and will reduce the product quantity from inventory automatically. how to write a code for reduce product quantity using ajax.

Comment: If it is automatic, then after the order has been processed, query the new quantity then update the view. Either do this before you return from the POST SalesOrder or make a new request in the previous AJAX success handler.

Comment: And as Tisa suggested, it would help us if you removed the unnecessary code from your question -- we just need to see the parts relevant to the quantity update. For example, we don't need code for the total sum.

Comment: I removed unnecessary code. and when I am clicking the save order and product quantity will automatically reduce from database. How to do with ajax?

Comment: Do I need to add modal part as well?

Comment: @RamzyAhamed You can pass the product data to action, and then minus the data.quantity,could you please share your model design? Are the product properties included in Order model or it's a individual model?

Comment: I have shared all three models include ordermodel, orderdetailmodel and product model